# How to store and retrieve image using NodeJS and MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, gridfs, multer-gridfs-storage

everyone. I'm still new to NodeJs and Mongodb and i would like some help when it comes to adding and retrieving an image depending on a user in my database. I created this mongoose schema and I have as a field "img" that I would like to use to store images and retrieve images. I've tried using GridFS and multer which i heard could do what i'm looking for but i'm unable to correctly store my image and then retrieve it. I use React as my frontend.

User model :

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const uniqueValidator = require("mongoose-unique-validator");

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    first: { type: String, required: true },
    last: { type: String, required: true },
    username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    img: {data: Buffer, type: String },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);
userSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator);
module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

User Controller :

```
const user = require('../models/user');
var User = require('../models/user');


exports.get_user = async (req, res, next) => {
    const { username, password } = req.body;
    let user_obj = await User.findOne({ username: username, password: password })
    res.status(200).json(user_obj);
}

exports.create_user = async (req, res, next) => {
    const { first, last, username, password, img} = req.body;
    const user_obj = new User({ first: first, last: last, username, password,img: req.file.filename});
     
     
    await user_obj.save();
    res.status(200).json('user creation succeded');
}
```

User Route :

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const userController = require('../controllers/userController');
const upload = require('../middleware/upload');

router.post("/create_user", upload.single('img'), userController.create_user);
//router.post("/create_user", userController.create_user);
router.post("/update_user", userController.update_user);
router.post("/get_user", userController.get_user);
router.get("/delete_user/:username", userController.delete_user);


module.exports = router;
```

Using this code i'm able to store an image but when i try to retrieve it using react as a frontend, the image dosen't render correctly on the browser.

I would really like some help, this is for a school project. Thank you, in advance!

Comment: I don't see an endpoint to retrieve the image or code to make sense of img from get_user. Or how you keep track of mime types.

Comment: Yeah, that's what i want help with because my app has authentication  and when  i register aa new user i want their photo to appear in their profile.

Comment: generally this is bad practices. We typically store assets like images in a cloud storage bucket (Azure, GCP, AWS), and only store the file's bucket id in the db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Images should be saved as static content then store only the path/url in database**

---

But if we have to save file data directly in DB, here's the code using multer. Only use for file smaller than 16mb. If larger, use GridFS.

Controller

```
const upload = multer()

app.post("/create_user", upload.single('img'), async (req, res) => {
  const user_obj = new User({
    img: req.file.buffer
  });

  await user_obj.save();
  res.json(user_obj);
});
```

Model

```
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    img: { type: Buffer },
  },
);
```

React on the frontend

```
function App() {

  const [image, setImage] = useState()

  const toBase64 = uInt8Array => btoa(String.fromCharCode(...uInt8Array));

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('http://localhost:8000/get_user')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        setImage(`data:image/jpeg;base64,${toBase64(data.img.data)}`);
      })
  }, [])

  return (
    <>
      {image && <img src={image} alt='logo' />}
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I do not have enough points to comment to clarify this.  When you say "render", does it look like a bunch of gibberish text on the page?  If so, for me, this was due to not sending the correct content type in the header when I served my file from my NodeJS web server.  I was sending "text/html" instead of "image/jpg" when a client requested a .jpg image.